# Python selenium and chromedriver, chrome page doesn't load when minimised

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

So here is my issue :

I'm trying to load a page with the browser minimised but it seems like it doesn't work.
I think there might be two reason : RAM management or the website prevent this.

So is there a way to make chrome think that it is on focus while it's not ?

Thanks a lot if you take time to respond to me !

EDIT : after some testing this issue only happens with chrome 87, so I think it's chrome ram management that the issue. The goal is to make chrome believe that I'm actually looking at the window.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the headless option

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
```

Comment: If the hardware is the issue, there is nothing we can do on the software side to help you with that. The only thing you can do is install a windows management software and keep your Chrome always focus, which is RAM-intensive to your device if the resource is quite limited.

Comment: Sorry I did not explain properly, it's not hardware. Chrome might have chnage they way they handle ram to use less.